# Tesseract - Preprocessing that Doesn't Affect Final Image

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, image-thresholding

I'm using the latest version of Tesseract (5.0), and I'm trying to determine whether or not I can insert some preprocessing steps that will -not- affect the form of the final image.

For example, I might start out with an image such
[as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWJ7F.jpg).

There are different levels of shadow/brightness, so I might use [adaptive Gaussian thresholding to avoid shadows during binarization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzCQS.jpg).

I will now run this through tesseract, with the hope of creating an OCR'd PDF in the end. However, I want the image that the end user (and I) see to be the full-color, original image, with the text from the transformed image underlaid

Is there a way to manage this? Or am I completely missing the point here.

Comment: You can use the indices of pixels = 0 and replace them with the usual colour. It can be attempted in OpenCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was provided an answer on another forum, and wanted to share it here.

Instead of using the built in PDF option in Tesseract, I used the hOCR setting. My pipeline went:

1. Preprocess image (thresholding, etc)
2. Run tesseract with the following command: tesseract example1.jpg example1 -l eng hocr
3. Use the hocr-pdf module from Ocropus to merge the hocr'd material with the ORIGINAL IMAGE, no preprocessing.

Comment: Just to be safe (in terms of copyright for that other forum), you should probably provide a link to it. Format it like this: `[another forum](https:\\xxx.yyy.xxx)`

Comment: Hey there, great username-- this isn't a copy/paste of the answer, which was more along the lines of "tesseract's main purpose is to extract text from images". Above is all original content.

Comment: OK, cool. Sorry for any misunderstanding. But linking that forum is still OK, if you *want* to do it.